# Multiplying an array in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am reading a specific column from a `csv` file. I want to multiply the elements of this array with `2`. When I do so, the array size is doubling instead of multiplying each element with `2`. I have shared the `CSV` file. I also present the current and expected outputs.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

B = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep=',', usecols=['sigma'], squeeze=True)
print("B[0] =",B[0]*2)
```

The CSV file looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUqzg.png)

The current output is

```
B[0] = [array([[0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [array([[0.02109],
       [0.02109]])]
```

The expected output is

```
B[0] = [array([[.04218],
       [.04218]])]
```

Comment: More details about your csv file.... like sharing a portion of it, would be very helpful.

Comment: can you add sample of csv file. it would help to reproduce

Comment: Can you add the output of `B.to_dict()` to your question?

Comment: I have shared the snapshot of the ```csv``` file .

Comment: `B[0]` is not a np.array, it's a native python list.

Comment: Given that `csv` I expect that the dataframe cell is actually a string,  not list, and certainly not an array.  The pandas display tends to blur these defferences.  `B.to_numpy()` might give a clearer idea of what's in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col" : [[0.2, 0.3],[0.3, 0.4],[0.4, 0.5],[0.5, 0.6]]
})
```

Multiply it by 2

```
df.col = df.col.apply(lambda x: [num * 2 for num in x])
```

Result

```
    col
0   [0.4, 0.6]
1   [0.6, 0.8]
2   [0.8, 1.0]
3   [1.0, 1.2]
```